# ERROR: This recovery media only functions on Dell and Alienware systems

Tags: dell, 16.04

We purchased new dell system OptiPlex 7440 AIO. This system coming with default Ubuntu 12.04, but when I'm trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 it's showing the following error before installation.

[image: IMG:]

I tried [these](http://www.dell.com/support/Article/us/en/19/SLN297060/EN) steps, but had no luck.

Comment: What happens when you click "Continue" on the error message?

Comment: @NickWeinberg Both "Back" and "Continue" buttons are disabled. There is only one option that is "Quit"!

Comment: Please sum up shortly the linked information so that people who want to help don't have to read more than your question.

Answer (score 4):

Got the solution :)

Here are the steps that we need to change under boot menu

1. Select **Legacy** option in Boot List Option
2. Under Boot Sequence uncheck **Diskette Drive** option.

   - [image: Reference Screenshot]
3. Disable Secure Boot

   - To disable it, Go to Secure Boot > Secure Boot Enable > Select **Disabled** radio
4. Now reboot the computer, and boot from your bootable device with Try Ubuntu without installation option
5. Install GParted application and delete first partition from it
6. Now you can able to install Ubuntu without any error

Answer (score 0):

First, **disable** UEFI.

Next, enable legacy boot.

Then download the 16.04 ISO from http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso

Burn it to a DVD, and insert the DVD into the drive.

Now reboot the computer, and boot from the DVD.

When you get to the main menu in Ubuntu, make sure to install with the option to completely format the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

I have an answer for this problem, but it may not be the perfect answers.

When I faced the same situation what I did was booted a live windows cd & reached the point where to install Windows on HDD. I formated the entire hard disk and quit the windows installation procedure. Now I have a fresh HDD (1tb free space). Then tried installing Ubuntu 64 bit in uefi mode, the installation process was perfectly completed and have my edubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Ubuntu software center in your computer and search for 'Dell Recovery ' and remove it. Now you can boot from your bootable USB.It worked for my new Dell lap

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. Gave up trying to find a 'soft' fix for this and ended up buying a replacement disk and retaining the old one as a backup (cost circa 40 GBP brand new). My laptop is about four years old: Inspiron 15 3000 Series (Intel(R)) - 3552. It has no CD drive or RJ45 socket. Latest Ubuntu 20.04 installed fine after that.